# The probability to have same hole cards on two tables of TH poker.

Tags: probability

I like to play TH poker. I usually play online. Usually I play on many tables and I noted that sometime hole cards are the same on different table. So i just wondering (as a math fun) how is the probability of hold the two hands of the same class? To explain better, we define hands as `JsTd` and `JcTh` as the same class hand, because thay have the same strong. `9c9h` and `9d9s` are the same class too, and so on. If at table $A$ i have two hole cards and at table $B$ other two hole cards, which is the probability of holding the same class two hole cards on two tables?

Comment: Don't you also have to consider that JsTd is not the same as JcTc? Same suited hands are stronger.

Comment: of course, indeed in the example are all off suited.

Comment: The probability wil depend on the type of hand you have; if you have a pocket pair, the chance that someone eles has the 'same' hand is much less than if you had non-pairing cards.

Comment: I am sorry, you misundertood my questiion. I fixed the formulation.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's better. Do you want to know what are the odds that you will have the same hand at two different tables?

Comment: yes, you right.

Comment: ok, then the number of hands dealt at each table is irrelevant, assuming the cards were fairly shuffled. And the comment from @UnkleRhaukus applies if you want to know after seeing your hand at one table, what are the odds that it is the same at the other table.

Comment: As a side note: the reason the number of other players affects your odds of winning, is that there are more chances that someone has a better hand than you. The odds of getting any two particular cards though at a table is 1/1326, regardless of how many players there are.

Comment: no, you wrong. I am talking about the cards that belongs to tha same class. So rougly 2/(13*13) because the order doesn't matter.

Comment: I wasn't referring to combinations of cards based on your definition of the same class, I was referring to combinations of cards which one can tell apart from each other. As you point out, order does not matter; I took this into account. I didn't consider the rest of the requirements for hands being considered the same though, otherwise I would have posted it as an answer. The probability I posted was, for example, the odds of getting the cards (Jd3c) with exactly those two suits where order doesn't matter: 52 choose 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $13$ different pairs that come in $6$ different suit combinations and $\binom{13}2=78$ different non-pairs that come in $4$ suited and $12$ offsuit varieties ($6\cdot13+(4+12)\cdot78=1326=\binom{52}2$).

The probability of getting a particular one of these classes twice is the square of the probability of getting it once, so we need to sum the squared probabilities:

$$
13\left(\frac6{1326}\right)^2+78\left(\frac4{1326}\right)^2+78\left(\frac{12}{1326}\right)^2=\frac{83}{11271}\approx0.007364\;.
$$

Comment: ...so, in 100 hands, if i found for example 5 of that same hole cards on average, means that the number generator does not work properly?

Comment: @emanuele: Yes, if that's the long-term average, something's wrong. However, if it only happens once that you get $5$ matches in $100$ hands, it might be OK, the probability for that to happen is about $1$ in $1000$.

Comment: Where is the term for the number of players at the table?

Comment: @Unkle: There isn't one; as Tim pointed out in a comment under the question, the number of players is irrelevant here.

Comment: @joriki, ah. I see now (the question has changes slightly) that the player is at two tables and comparing their own hands.